# How to simulate sfdx:force:org:open?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, selenium

I want to write few automation that will run on cli and use `sfdx force:org:open`. How do I simulate the command?
The automation needs the url that sfdx... command leads to in the browser.Example I want to be able to reach the page using selenium. Though I can put this command itself in automation script but that will not link selenium to it.
Also lets say I obtain the url somehow in my script, if I access that link using selenium will I able to or will I encounter any access issue?

So if I run the command from python using subprocess

```
cmnd='sfdx force:org:open'
run(cmnd,shell=True)
```

I am able to access the org like usual, but I want to access the url in code without actually accessing the link in browser.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @DavidReed I have added the try so far, but all I have are question marks ahead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the `-r` flag to the command will return the URL instead of attempting to open in browser

`sfdx force:org:open -r`